# In angular 2 how to get kendo object like in Jquery

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui

I have already used Kendo UI with jQuery in the past but now that I'm using it with Angular 2 there are few things I'm missing.
Can we get kendo objects in Angular 2 the same way we were doing in jQuery, using an id selector?

```
var obj = $('#IdName').data("kendoDropDownList");
var data = obj .dataItem();
var dataSource = $('#IdName').data("kendoGrid").dataSource;
```

etc...

If it is possible then can you explain me how? If it's not possible then how will I be able to get reference to dataSource, Kendo object, selected value, filter, etc...?

Answer (score 2):

In your components TypeScript class try this:

```
export class ExampleComponent implements OnInit {

   @ViewChild('myElement') elRef: ElementRef;

   constructor() {
   }
   ngOnInit() { 
     const nativeElement = this.elRef.nativeElement;
     const data = nativeElement.data("kendoGrid").dataSource;
     console.log(data);
   }
}
```

And an html example:

```
<any-html-element #myElement></any-html-element>
```

Note the @ViewChild. With ViewChild you get a reference to a html element. With .nativeElement you get the actual HTML Element like you would do it in jQuery.
Just pass in the ID (in HTML prefixed with hash (#))